# I want to just be able to use <h:outputText> rather than having to create a <h:dataTable>

Tags: java, html, javabeans

So I have

```
<h:dataTable value="#{sportBean.sportName}" var="item">
    <f:facet name="header">
    </f:facet>
    <h:column>
        <div id="sportName"><h:outputText rendered="#{item.sportName == 'Golf'}" value="#{item.sportName}" /></div>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

but rather than having to create a dataTable, I want to be able to just put it straight through outputText. I hope you guys understand?

Comment: How is this question related to CSS? That is, why is it tagged [tag:CSS]?

Comment: @connexo I guess it's not haha

Comment: Then remove irrelevants tag(s) by editing your question.